# what's wrong when css media query only allows new styles addition but not old ones modifications

Tags: html, css

```css
  .livesearch{
  width: 228px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-right: 72px;
  margin-left: auto;
  }
  
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .livesearch{
  width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #EEE;
 }
 }
```

And it is accepting   background-color: #EEE; only (in my page)
More, there are other classes in the same media query, that I've removed here for semplification, and both style additions and modifications works in them. The problem exists only with the one I wrote here

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i think something is missing .. ah! it's the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

You can see the difference on full page resize

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.livesearch {
  width: 228px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-right: 72px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .livesearch {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="livesearch">Test</div>
```